# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'eh', but it was: a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from a firestore database in my react app but it doesn't show up on the page. In the browser console I get an error saying "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'eh', but it was: a function"
Here is my code :

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase-config";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function MemberPage() {

    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const membersCollectionRef = useCallback(() => collection(db, "members"),[]);

    useEffect(() => {
            const getMembers = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(membersCollectionRef);
            setMembers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        };
    
        getMembers();
    }, [membersCollectionRef]);

    return (...)}
```

[The database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbXlI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be an issue with using `useCallback` Hooks

try this one please

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase-config";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function MemberPage() {

    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    
    const getMembers = async () => {
        const dataSnap = await getDocs(collection(db, "members"));
        setMembers(dataSnap.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMembers();
    }, []);

    return (...)}
```

Comment: Now i get an error saying "Compiled with problems:
ERROR
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Update: It works. I can't thank you enough! The second error was caused because when i was displaying the data I didn't add toString() method